# Hardhat not connecting error

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Hello all i am building  a fileuploader using ipfs.when i try to connect to my wallet using hardhat local network i am getting hardhat cant connect error and option to switch network.My hardhat is running in terminal properly.any help will be appreciated.
i am attaching hardhat.config file
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

```
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18",
  networks:{
    hardhat:{
      chainId:31337
    },
  },
  paths:{
    artifacts:"./drive/src/artifact",
  }
};
```